# stateless EJB3 bean invoked from request-scoped JAX-RS web service accumulates state

Tags: ejb-3.0, jax-rs

I have the following situation: Request-scoped **JAX-RS** service invokes stateless **EJB3** bean and the EJB3 bean retains state between successive invocation of the web service from a client.

Code as follows:

#### web service

```
@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
@Path("/actions")
public class CounterFrontEnd {

    @EJB
    private ICounterService.ILocal counterService;

    @GET @Produces("application/text;") @Path("/counter")
    public String counter() {
        return String.format("%d ", counterService.incCounter());
    }
```

#### stateless EJB3 bean

```
@Stateless
@Local (ICounterService.ILocal.class)
@Remote(ICounterService.IRemote.class)
public class CounterService implements ICounterService.ILocal, ICounterService.IRemote {

    public int counter = 0;
    @Override
    public int incCounter() {
        return counter++;
    }
```

I then invoke the service with the following python script:

```
for i in range(100):
  os.system( 'curl  http://somewhere:8080/counter-ws/rest/actions/counter' )
```

Surprisingly, the output is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the container (happens) to give you the same bean-instance every time, not something you should rely on.

Stateless session-beans should not rely on instance-variables like in your example.

From java ee tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/javaeetutorial6.pdf

> **Stateless Session Beans**
>
> A stateless session bean does not maintain a conversational state with
> the client. When a client invokes the methods of a stateless bean, the
> bean’s instance variables may contain a state speciic to that client
> but only for the duration of the invocation. When the method is
> inished, the client-speciic state should not be retained. Clients may,
> however, change the state of instance variables in pooled stateless
> beans, and this state is held over to the next invocation of the
> pooled stateless bean. Except during method invocation, all instances
> of a stateless bean are equivalent, allowing the EJB container to
> assign an instance to any client. That is, the state of a stateless
> session bean should apply across all clients.